# How to Link ComboBox with Database and Show values in TextBox if Select ComboBox in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to select a database value from Combobox that has been populated from the database and displayed in Combobox, and I want to click on any option in Combobox and it should display values in the textbox but upon doing so, I get an error that says: data is null. This method or property cannot be called on NULL values.

The error:
https://snipboard.io/Rn6YwC.jpg   CONTINUED SCREENSHOT: https://snipboard.io/i3l8MO.jpg

This is my code:

```
 Private Sub CollectionEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=golden_star"



    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from golden_star.loan"

        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)



        READER = Command.ExecuteReader

        While READER.Read()
            Dim sname = READER.GetString("account_name")
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(sname)

        End While

        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=golden_star"


    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from golden_star.loan where account_name = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' "

        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)

        READER = Command.ExecuteReader

        While READER.Read
            txtID.Text = READER.GetInt32("id")
            DatePick.Text = READER.GetDateTime("date")
            txtName.Text = READER.GetString("account_name")
            txtCollections.Text = READER.GetInt32("collections")
            txtContact.Text = READER.GetInt32("contact")
        End While

        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The first code is loading data from the database and putting it on Combobox when form onLoad and the second form is Combobox selected index changed. Selecting one of the lists and displaying it on the textbox.

I can't seem to find the error that's causing the error to pop up. Where did I go wrong that it pops when selecting the list values in Combobox?

Comment: Please only add relevant tags. If your question is about showing data from MySQL in a WinForms app then what has it got to do with MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT *` when populating the `ComboBox` and then ignoring all but one column? If you only need one column then only get one column. If you're getting all columns then use all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any code at all when the user makes a selection. You're getting all the data on the first query so just use that data. Populate a `DataTable` and bind it to all the controls, preferably via a `BindingSource`. The other controls will then update automatically when a selection is made.

```vb
Using connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here"),
      command As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM golden_star.loan", connection)
    connection.Open()

    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim table As New DataTable

        table.Load(reader)
        BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    End Using
End Using

With ComboBox1
    .DisplayMember = "account_name"
    .ValueMember = "id"
    .DataSource = BindingSource1
End With

txtID.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(txtID.Text), BindingSource1, "id")
DatePick.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(DatePick.Value), BindingSource1, "date")
'etc
```

Note that, for the `DateTimePicker`, you should be using the `Value` property, which is type `DateTime`, not the `Text` property.

Note that the `BindingSource` gets added to the form in the designer, along with the controls.

Comment: So I should write the code above on Combobox selected index changed OR upon form load? I wrote the code above on Private Sub ComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged. Upon running the program the ComboBox is not displaying the records from the database. @jmcilhinney

Comment: @SalwaHamim, read the words I wrote instead of just copying the code.

Comment: I understood your point. I shouldn't have to select all columns when only need one, use only one query, populate the data in the Combobox and bind it to textbox respectively etc. I started with vb.net and was only taught the basics of arithmetic etc but (not connecting to a database or bind the data etc) so had to teach myself that. The only part I was confused about is there are two parts Form_load and combo box selected index changed, When doing subcode execution should I be doing this on form load or on Combobox selected index changed? I'm sorry for bombarding you w/ questions @jmcilhinney

Comment: @SalwaHamim, I specifically said *'You don't need any code at all when the user makes a selection"* so how many options does that leave? I specifically said *"You're getting all the data on the first query so just use that data"* and that first query is already in the `Load` event handler so why is there even a question? Being new to VB doesn't mean that you can't read the first two sentences of my answer.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney I wanted to ask one more question about binding data from comboBox to textbox, the code works but when try to refresh values from the database only either of them works i.e. binding data to textbox or refresh.

Comment: @SalwaHamim, I suggest that you post a new question specific to that. The comments on an existing answer are not the place to ask a new question.